# How can I ensure that a figure is displayed following another one?

Tags: floats

I have two figures in my document:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}
\caption{Notation used in the big complicated table}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}
\caption{Big complicated table}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a way to ensure that the notation table stays close to the big table? Right now when Latex renders my document its pushing the big table to a later page leaving the notation table behind.

I suspect that this might require putting everything in the same figure. Is there a way to do that while still maintaining the helpful captions?

Comment: just delete the central `\end{figure} \begin{figure}` you can have two captions. Why use `figure` not `table` for the foat?

Comment: Could you write that as an answer, please? As for why not `table` its because I wasn't aware it existed.

Comment: Why even use two captions? Put the *complicated table* and the notation in one `table`-environment and use just one caption. Since both stay together, a caption for the notation is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the two `tabular` environments both fit on a single page, you may want to use a single `table` (not `figure`!) environment to contain them.

For instance, the following code may work for you:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{...} ... \end{tabular}
\caption{Notation used in the big complicated table}

\bigskip    % create a bit of vertical separation  
\begin{tabular}{...} ... \end{tabular}
\caption{Big complicated table}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is frowned upon, but it should work at the cost of having perhaps slightly less well document layout before and after the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}
\caption{Notation used in the big complicated table}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}
\caption{Big complicated table}
\end{figure
\end{document}
```

The `float` package forces floats to appear in the document right where you declared them in the tex file if you use the `[H]` specifier.

Comment: Note that the OP asked that the two tabulars be kept together, *not* that the tables be prevented from floating entirely. With your setup, it's still possible that the tables appear on two separate pages.